# Android API demos uninstall

Tags: android, api, uninstallation, demos

Hi I am unable to uninstall the API Demos app which got installed when I was checking out the API Demo's examples in eclipse. Now I try to uninstall I get a message 'Failure' I tried from the device as well as the command prompt with same result.

Any help

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think i got the soln. Go to `Settings > Security > Device Administrators`. If you see Api Demo just un-check it and then try un-installing again.

NOTE: The instructions here should work on all platforms too. I only tested a few like 2.2, 2.3.3 etc.